# How to determine if drawn object is visible on Canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I recently came across this question for an HTML5 certification exam and I cant seem to understand how to figure out the correct answer given the details provided. I believe the correct answers are A/B/E but I have no idea how to solve, any guidance?

If a circle is drawn onto a canvas at the position x, y, which statements are true when the ball is visible within a rectangle of dimension top, bottom, left and right? (Choose three.)

```
a) (x <top AND x>bottom) OR (y> left AND y < right)
b) (x > top AND x < bottom) AND (y> left AND y < right)
c) (x < top AND x > bottom) AND (y < left AND y > right)
d) (x <top OR x >bottom) AND (y >left OR y < right)
e) (x > top OR x < bottom) AND (y >left OR y > right)
```

Comment: The exam question seems flawed. Why is a rectangle defined by four dimensions, when two suffice (width, height)?

Comment: None. It makes no sense to check x against top and bottom, and y against left and right.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but I am only trying to understand how the answers a/b/e (I have the answer key) was derived

Comment: Are you 100% sure that these are the propositions? Once again, checking x against top and bottom makes no sense, and y against left and right neither. If you are 100% sure that these are indeed the correct propositions and solutions, then drop this test right now because its authors were drunk when they wrote it and it won't test anything but your lucky charm.